# Is it okay to have a Stack Exchange site that is a subset of another one?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, off-topic

For example:

**Would it be okay to ask a code improvement/review question on *Stack Overflow* rather than asking it on *CodeReview*?**

**Shouldn't these kind of questions be moved to *[CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)*?**

If not, I don't know what is the idea of having another Stack Exchange site if you can ask that question on another one (like Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per

https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions **based on actual problems that you face**

If you have *functioning* code you don't really have a *problem*, do you?

Thus, code review is for *functioning* code that you think can be made better in some nebulous abstract way --  aesthetically, speed, layout, etc.

Comment: That's what I thought, and I asked this question to be sure about it. The purpose of this question was because of a comment I placed on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215799/is-there-a-way-to-shorten-a-conditional-that-contains-a-bunch-of-boolean-comparis and the answer I received from a moderator.

Comment: By the way, if you have functioning code you can still have a lot of problems. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

SO gets a *lot* of questions every day. Moving some of them to sister sites like Programmers.SE or CodeReview.SE allows SO itself to be more focused and more helpful to its users.

In a sense, they are not *subsets* of StackOverflow, but rather complementary sites. StackOverflow's purpose is to contain questions about specific code implementation problems. Programmers.SE is still related to programming and software development, but deals with more subjective issues. Code Review is there just for review of working code for style/potential problems.

The key difference between SO and Code Review is that the former requires your code to have a problem that prevents it from working. You could post your broken code to SO, get help with fixing it, and then post the final working result to Code Review to see if you could've written it better.